# Sorting gives inconsistent results, due to loop bound

Tags: c

Program Design, our first homework assignment was to take 4 integer values, add the 2 highest together and subtract the lowest two and square that result. Finally, compare the 2 values together to see if they are equal or not.

For example, if you were to enter: `20 10 60 40`

You'd get

```
60 + 40 = 100
```

and

```
20 - 10 = 10 --> 10^2 = 100
```

So, `100 == 100`

I wrote my program and tested it for various values which all returned correct results. My professor told me my program failed for all 10 test inputs and he sent me the results he got. The results he got aren't the same as mine, and I don't know what's going on. I emailed him, and he told me one of my for loops has incorrect bounds. He's right, but I still get the right results, so...?

Here's the code, any help would be appreciated!

```
/*
 // Author: Jesse W
 // Assignment 1

 // Desciption:
 // This program inputs four integer numbers a, b, c and d and
 // determines if the sum of the two largest numbers is the same
 // as the squared difference of the two smallest numbers
 */

#include <stdio.h>

/* Complete the code for this program below */

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d, f, k, swap;
    int array_size = 4;
    int return_val;
    int sum, difference, square;
    int small_1, small_2, large_1, large_2;
    int array[array_size];

    //Gather input
    //printf("Enter integer values for a, b, c and d.\n");
    return_val = scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);

    //Validate input
    if (return_val != 4)
    {
        printf("INVALID INPUT\n");
    }
    else
    {
        //Assign values to array
        array[0] = a;
        array[1] = b;
        array[2] = c;
        array[3] = d;

        //Sort array
        for (k = 0 ; k < ( array_size - 1 ); k++)
        {
            for (f = 0 ; f < array_size ; f++)
            {
                if (array[f] > array[f+1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
                {
                    swap       = array[f];
                    array[f]   = array[f+1];
                    array[f+1] = swap;
                }
            }
        }

        //Assign sorted values to new variables
        small_1 = array[0];
        small_2 = array[1];
        large_1 = array[2];
        large_2 = array[3];

        //Compute math
        sum = large_1 + large_2;
        difference = small_1 - small_2;
        square = difference * difference;

        //Compute logic
        if(sum == square)
        {
            printf("%d equals %d.\n", sum, square);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d does not equal %d.\n", sum, square);
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `http://ideone.com/Q29DX2` I used `100 20 40 80` so your answer should be `100 + 80 = 180` and `20 - 40 = -20`, and square is `400`....but your output says `120 does not equal 361.`...so your professor is correct :) Happy debugging...

Comment: Despite the fact you shouldn't write code like that, you have an off-by-one error within your loop as you access array[array_size] which would be uninitialized value, that is either 0 or some random garbage. This can screw up things quite a bit. I'd recommend using a debugger in cases you encounter such "anomalies".

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of debugging, where you can get the right answer and never know that your code is wrong. As everyone has already pointed out, you're accessing the array beyond its bounds. Also, your sort uses 12 compare-and-swaps when it only needs 5, but let's get it right before you worry about that. :-)

Comment: We are not here to fight your professor but to give you technical answers. So from the start your question title is a lousy one.

Comment: @JensGustedt Ya know what's easier than criticizing? Fixing the problem.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, I don't agree. Formulating a correct question is an important step for students like this one to understand the problem.

Comment: @JensGustedt There was nothing wrong with the formulation here. I only fixed the title. Many other students hit the same issue, so this is definitely not too localized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`f` ranges up to `array_size - 1`

```
        for (f = 0 ; f < array_size ; f++)
```

but in that case you access `array[ f + 1 ]` which is `array[ array_size ]`

```
                array[f]   = array[f+1];
                array[f+1] = swap;
```

This results in undefined behavior. Since the value one past the end is effectively sorted as part of the array, whether the program works or not depends whether the uninitialized value is larger than all the input values.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! It's pretty clear now why it was working for me, but not for him. I guess that is the answer I was looking for because I couldn't see why over-sorting would be an issue!

Comment: @JesseWalton Yeah, it can get scrambled into the middle of the list. Please don't forget to click the checkmark at upper left :) .

Answer (score 4):

The problem is indeed the upper bound on your inner `for` loop; it's causing you to read past the end of your array, which causes **undefined behaviour**.

It's entirely possible that the resulting program still prints the correct results on your machine, but there is no guarantee that it will work on anyone else's. Hence undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner loop will end up accessing `array[4]`, which triggers undefined behavior. As soon as you trigger undefined behavior, you can't guarantee anything about the program after that point.

What's likely *actually* happening, though, is that on your computer, `array[4]` *just happens* to be larger than `array[3]` and you keep those in the same order. On your professor's computer, you swap them (probably corrupting some other variable), making `array[3]` be that undefined value.

Answer (score 1):

Since your program's output depends totally on the value of `array[4]`, where `array` is an array of length 4, its behavior is completely unpredictable: there's no way, from the source, to guess what value will happen to be in memory at location `array + 4`.

(In fact, it's even worse than that — your program invokes *undefined behavior*, which means that it's allowed to do absolutely anything at all, up to including sending your professor a vulgar and insulting e-mail that looks like it's from you. But in practice, it's likely to print one of its expected outputs, there's just really no way to guess *which* one.)

Comment: It would be amusing if the professor showed students "the output" of their programs, and for students whose programs invoked UB, arbitrarily chose the output to be something of the form you described. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change your sort loop to this

```
    for (k = 0 ; k < array_size ; k++)
    {
        for (f = 0 ; f < (array_size -1) ; f++)
        {
            if (array[f] > array[f+1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
            {
                swap       = array[f];
                array[f]   = array[f+1];
                array[f+1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's still an O(n^2) sort, doing 12 compare-and-swaps when you only need 5, but at least it works.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Both loop bounds can be `array_size - 1` because that is the number of steps to send a value from one "side" of the array to the other. So the correct bubble sort is just 9 compare and swaps.